# Nested lists in strict XHTML1.0 for ebook invalid

Tags: epub, nested-lists, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am working on an ebook that contains many nested lists (both OL and UL) and one page is not valid. I wish to keep them as lists for semantic and organizational reasons. Here's the format I am going for:

1. Question

   - Subquestion
   - Subquestion

Paragraph explaining answers

2. Question

   - Subquestion
   - Subquestion

Paragraph explaining answers

H2 Section break

3. Question

   - Subquestion
   - Subquestion

Paragraph explaining answers

4. Question

   - Subquestion
   - Subquestion

Paragraph explaining answers

And my abbreviated code:

```
<ol>
    <li>Question 1
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>

    <li>Question 2
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>

<h2>Section break</h2>

    <li>Question 3
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>

    <li>Question 4
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>

</ol>
```

Now this looks great in-browser, except I get an tag mismatch error on the last line (the closing ol tag), preventing anything after the ordered list from displaying. I am not allowed to break format (ie put all paragraphs at the end of the OL) and would rather not simply use numerals for the OL.

Are paragraph and header tags not allowed nested inside lists? Is there a workaround to keep numbering and formatting consistent? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put anything in an `ol` but `li` as detailed [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html).  You would be best off doing it like this:

```
<ol>
    <li>Question 1
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>

<ol>
    <li>Question 2
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>

    <h2>Section break</h2>

<ol>
    <li>Question 3
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>

<ol>
    <li>Question 4
     <ul>
      <li>subquestion</li>
      <li>subquestion</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response! Unfortunately, having four separate OLs results in four #1s, not 1-4 as I intend. Is there a CSS rule to dictate the OL li's number? I realize this is probably a hack but it is essential to ensure the OL contains consistent numbering.

Comment: @user2540402 You can use the `start="#"` attribute, obviously replacing `#` with what you want it to start with, but it was deprecated in HTML 4.01.  It is still supported in HTML5 though so you're still good.

Comment: That's new to me, thanks! EPUBs and MOBIs must be developed in strict XHTML1.0, as far as I know, but I no longer get the mismatched tag error and it validates. Thanks again @phantom!

Answer (score 0):

What @phantom said isn't entirely true. You can "embed" a para in a list item. Where your original example breaks down is that you cannot have a heading within a ordered list; that is what is not permitted.

Here's what you should do:

```
<ol>
    <li>Question 1
        <ul>
            <li>subquestion</li>
            <li>subquestion</li>
        </ul>

    <!-- The following places the paragraph within the <li> element,
         giving it a paragraph space/line break above and no bullet. -->

    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p> <!-- para wrapped in the -->

    </li> <!-- close the list item. -->

    <li>Question 2
        <ul>
            <li>subquestion</li>
            <li>subquestion</li>
        </ul>
     <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>
     </li>
</ol> <!-- End the ordered list since it cannot contain a heading tag -->

<h2>Section break</h2>

<ol>
    <li>Question 3
        <ul>
            <li>subquestion</li>
            <li>subquestion</li>
        </ul>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>
    </li>

    <li>Question 4
        <ul>
            <li>subquestion</li>
            <li>subquestion</li>
        </ul>
    <p>Paragraph explaining answers</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```